# Issues with updating to pandas 0.17. with several warnings

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I am having an issue updating from pandas 0.14 to 0.17 running on Debian 8. 
As far as I have been researching the issue and checked for all the possibly missing components (libraries, compilers, dependencies...) all that were suggested I have installed and running, the issue possibly lies in a missing path or a component that is not up to date causing the countless warnings in the process, tough at the end it says pandas installed successfully.  But it never was. 
In several threads it was written that this was a system not a pandas issue, but I surely cannot solve the problem. Attached are the issues related to my instalation:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
Downloading/unpacking pandas from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pandas/pandas-0.17.0.tar.gz#md5=55d34c4d5655c94ca30a59dea6b36316
  Downloading pandas-0.17.0.tar.gz (6.5MB): 6.5MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-ZJD_A8/pandas/setup.py) egg_info for package pandas

warning: no files found matching 'README.rst'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
warning: no directories found matching 'examples'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '#*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.png' found anywhere in distribution
Downloading/unpacking python-dateutil from https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/p/python-dateutil/python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=c817289a1d95a355cc088e2292791a77 (from pandas)
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (188kB): 188kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking pytz>=2011k from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pytz/pytz-2015.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=c1cd852eedca903c008c9dc44c195c77 (from pandas)
  Downloading pytz-2015.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (476kB): 476kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking numpy>=1.7.0 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.10.1.tar.gz#md5=3fed2b50906bc19018cec5fa26168aa5 (from pandas)
  Downloading numpy-1.10.1.tar.gz (4.0MB): 4.0MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-ZJD_A8/numpy/setup.py) egg_info for package numpy
    Running from numpy source directory.

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
Downloading/unpacking six>=1.5 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/s/six/six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=3ab558cf5d4f7a72611d59a81a315dc8 (from python-dateutil->pandas)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pandas, python-dateutil, pytz, numpy, six
  Found existing installation: pandas 0.14.1
    Not uninstalling pandas at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
  Running setup.py install for pandas
    UPDATING build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pandas/_version.py
    set build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pandas/_version.py to '0.17.0'
    skipping 'pandas/index.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'pandas.index' extension
    i586-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Ipandas/src/klib -Ipandas/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pandas/index.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/pandas/index.o
    In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1761:0,
                     from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                     from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from pandas/index.c:242:
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
      ^
    In file included from pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:3:0,
                     from pandas/index.c:246:
    pandas/src/klib/khash.h: In function ‘kh_del_str’:
    pandas/src/klib/khash.h:155:38: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
     #define __ac_set_isdel_true(flag, i) (0)
```

Comment: hmh, those warnings are probably not responsible for any failures you see.

Comment: Problem solved. The key to this instalation was to build pandas from source code. Meaning, downloading the tar.gz file, untar and ran two simple commands in the terminal. 1. python setup.py build and 2. python setup.py install. Hope this will help once somebody gets stucked with a similar issue.